# How to get the first day of the current week and month?

Tags: java, android, date

I have the date of several events expressed in **milliseconds**[1], and I want to know which events are inside the current week and the current month, but I can't figure out how to obtain the first day (day/month/year) of the running week and convert it to milliseconds, the same for the first day of the month.

```
[1]Since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: How to get the first day of the month? It's the one numbered `1`...

Comment: Yeah, but how to get the name of the 1st day of the month?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This week in milliseconds:

```
// get today and clear time of day
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

// get start of this week in milliseconds
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.println("Start of this week:       " + cal.getTime());
System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());

// start of the next week
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
System.out.println("Start of the next week:   " + cal.getTime());
System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

This month in milliseconds:

```
// get today and clear time of day
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

// get start of the month
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("Start of the month:       " + cal.getTime());
System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());

// get start of the next month
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("Start of the next month:  " + cal.getTime());
System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: also need clear am_pm for start of a day
cal.clear(Calendar.AM_PM);

Comment: @keshin: True. I replaced the lines `cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);` with `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);` like instructed in the javadoc of Calendar.

Comment: @COMEFROM why do you suggest to use clear?whats the benefit if i use and what error would I expect If I dont use?

Comment: @SpringLearner: Days and weeks and months all begin and end at midnight. However, Calendar.getInstance does not usually return a Calendar instance pointing to a midnight (00:00:00.000). So, to find out a beginning or the end of a day (or a week or a month), resetting the time of the day is needed.

Comment: @COMEFROM even I do not clear then also it worked so just interested why you made it

Comment: @SpringLearner: I do it because it is needed to solve the problem at hand this way. I can't really say anything about what you have done. If you have an alternative solution to this problem, then you could post an answer.

Comment: @COMEFROM no no,I do not have alternate answer,I did as you posted here but I was confused why you did clear.So asked,thanks anyway

Comment: @SpringLearner: Clearing is needed to make the Calendar instance point to a midnight instead of some other time of a day. That's all I can say about it. If you don't clear the time, then you'll probably have the Calendar pointing at some other time of a day. That's certainly not satisfactory if you need the first millisecond of a day.

Comment: Would be the answer!

Comment: In modern Java, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as `Calendar` have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 26):

The first day of week can be determined with help of [`java.util.Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) > calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // Substract 1 day until first day of week.
}
long firstDayOfWeekTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

The first day of month can be determined as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
while (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) > 1) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // Substract 1 day until first day of month.
}
long firstDayOfMonthTimestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Pretty verbose, yes.

---

Java 7 will come with a much improved Date and Time API ([JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/)). If you can't switch yet, then you can as far use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which makes it all less complicated:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp);
long firstDayOfWeekTimestamp = dateTime.withDayOfWeek(1).getMillis();
```

and

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp);
long firstDayOfMonthTimestamp = dateTime.withDayOfMonth(1).getMillis();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm on development of my first Android app, on a completely new world, the world of Java, and i'd never heard about joda but i'm not sure about joda+android.

Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Using JodaTime is just a matter of downloading the JAR and placing it in the classpath. As with every other "3rd party" library.

Comment: @cesar, where do you state in the question or in the tags that this is for Android?

Comment: Though keep in mind that jodatime may turn your 30kb app into a 300kb app.

Comment: Good answer. I suggest also passing a [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object to the DateTime constructor rather than implicitly rely on the JVM’s current default time zone to be assigned.

Answer (score 23):

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework in Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The old classes have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

The java.time framework is inspired by the highly-successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, and explained in the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `Instant`

The `Instant` class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The java.time framework has a resolution of nanoseconds, or 9 digits of a fractional second. Milliseconds is only 3 digits of a fractional second. Because [millisecond resolution](http://currentmillis.com) is common, java.time includes a handy factory method.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = 1446959825213L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( millisecondsSinceEpoch );
```

> millisecondsSinceEpoch: 1446959825213 is instant: 2015-11-08T05:17:05.213Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

To consider current week and current month, we need to apply a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

> In zoneId: America/Montreal that is: 2015-11-08T00:17:05.213-05:00[America/Montreal]

### Half-Open

In date-time work, we commonly use the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending in *exclusive*. Rather than try to determine the last split-second of the end of the week (or month), we get the first moment of the *following* week (or month). So a week runs from the first moment of Monday and goes up to *but not including* the first moment of the *following* Monday.

Let's the first day of the week, and last. The java.time framework includes a tool for that, the [`with`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) method and the [`ChronoField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) enum.

By default, java.time uses the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. So Monday is the first day of the week (1) and Sunday is last (7).

```
ZonedDateTime firstOfWeek = zdt.with ( ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK , 1 ); // ISO 8601, Monday is first day of week.
ZonedDateTime firstOfNextWeek = firstOfWeek.plusWeeks ( 1 );
```

> That week runs from: 2015-11-02T00:17:05.213-05:00[America/Montreal] to 2015-11-09T00:17:05.213-05:00[America/Montreal]

Oops! Look at the time-of-day on those values. We want the first moment of the day. The first moment of the day is not always `00:00:00.000` because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies. So we should let java.time make the adjustment on our behalf. To do that, we must go through the `LocalDate` class.

```
ZonedDateTime firstOfWeek = zdt.with ( ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK , 1 ); // ISO 8601, Monday is first day of week.
firstOfWeek = firstOfWeek.toLocalDate ().atStartOfDay ( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime firstOfNextWeek = firstOfWeek.plusWeeks ( 1 );
```

> That week runs from: 2015-11-02T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal] to 2015-11-09T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

And same for the month.

```
ZonedDateTime firstOfMonth = zdt.with ( ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH , 1 );
firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.toLocalDate ().atStartOfDay ( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime firstOfNextMonth = firstOfMonth.plusMonths ( 1 );
```

> That month runs from: 2015-11-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] to 2015-12-01T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

## `YearMonth`

Another way to see if a pair of moments are in the same month is to check for the same [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) value.

For example, assuming `thisZdt` and `thatZdt` are both `ZonedDateTime` objects:

```
boolean inSameMonth = YearMonth.from( thisZdt ).equals( YearMonth.from( thatZdt ) ) ;
```

### Milliseconds

I strongly recommend against doing your date-time work in milliseconds-from-epoch. That is indeed the way date-time classes tend to work internally, but we have the classes for a reason. Handling a count-from-epoch is clumsy as the values are not intelligible by humans so debugging and logging is difficult and error-prone. And, as we've already seen, different resolutions may be in play; old Java classes and Joda-Time library use milliseconds, while databases like Postgres use microseconds, and now java.time uses nanoseconds.

Would you handle text as bits, or do you let classes such as `String`, `StringBuffer`, and `StringBuilder` handle such details?

But if you insist, from a `ZonedDateTime` get an `Instant`, and from that get a milliseconds-count-from-epoch. But keep in mind **this call can mean loss of data**. Any microseconds or nanoseconds that you might have in your `ZonedDateTime`/`Instant` will be truncated (lost).

```
long millis = firstOfWeek.toInstant().toEpochMilli();  // Possible data loss.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: This is the only way to go if one is working with timezones. The old Calendar/Date does not cover it. Thanks for the post Basil, I found it very useful.

Answer (score 14):

Attention!

```
while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) > calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // Substract 1 day until first day of week.
}
```

is good idea, but there is some issue:
For example, i'm from Ukraine and calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek() in my country is 2 (Monday).
And today is 1 (Sunday). In this case calendar.add not called.

So, correct way is change ">" to "!=":

```
while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()) {...
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `java.time` package (since Java8 and late) to get start/end of day/week/month.
The util class example below:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {
    private static final ZoneId DEFAULT_ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of("UTC");

    public static LocalDateTime startOfDay() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID).with(LocalTime.MIN);
    }

    public static LocalDateTime endOfDay() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID).with(LocalTime.MAX);
    }

    public static boolean belongsToCurrentDay(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.isAfter(startOfDay()) && localDateTime.isBefore(endOfDay());
    }

    //note that week starts with Monday
    public static LocalDateTime startOfWeek() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID)
                .with(LocalTime.MIN)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    }

    //note that week ends with Sunday
    public static LocalDateTime endOfWeek() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID)
                .with(LocalTime.MAX)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    }

    public static boolean belongsToCurrentWeek(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.isAfter(startOfWeek()) && localDateTime.isBefore(endOfWeek());
    }

    public static LocalDateTime startOfMonth() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID)
                .with(LocalTime.MIN)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
    }

    public static LocalDateTime endOfMonth() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID)
                .with(LocalTime.MAX)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    }

    public static boolean belongsToCurrentMonth(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.isAfter(startOfMonth()) && localDateTime.isBefore(endOfMonth());
    }

    public static long toMills(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.atZone(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    }

    public static Date toDate(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID).toInstant());
    }

    public static String toString(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //day
        final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("Now: " + toString(now) + ", in mills: " + toMills(now));
        System.out.println("Start of day: " + toString(startOfDay()));
        System.out.println("End of day: " + toString(endOfDay()));
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(now) + "' belong to the current day? > " + belongsToCurrentDay(now));
        final LocalDateTime yesterday = now.minusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(yesterday) + "' belong to the current day? > " + belongsToCurrentDay(yesterday));
        final LocalDateTime tomorrow = now.plusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(tomorrow) + "' belong to the current day? > " + belongsToCurrentDay(tomorrow));
        //week
        System.out.println("Start of week: " + toString(startOfWeek()));
        System.out.println("End of week: " + toString(endOfWeek()));
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(now) + "' belong to the current week? > " + belongsToCurrentWeek(now));
        final LocalDateTime previousWeek = now.minusWeeks(1);
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(previousWeek) + "' belong to the current week? > " + belongsToCurrentWeek(previousWeek));
        final LocalDateTime nextWeek = now.plusWeeks(1);
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(nextWeek) + "' belong to the current week? > " + belongsToCurrentWeek(nextWeek));
        //month
        System.out.println("Start of month: " + toString(startOfMonth()));
        System.out.println("End of month: " + toString(endOfMonth()));
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(now) + "' belong to the current month? > " + belongsToCurrentMonth(now));
        final LocalDateTime previousMonth = now.minusMonths(1);
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(previousMonth) + "' belong to the current month? > " + belongsToCurrentMonth(previousMonth));
        final LocalDateTime nextMonth = now.plusMonths(1);
        System.out.println("Does '" + toString(nextMonth) + "' belong to the current month? > " + belongsToCurrentMonth(nextMonth));
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
Now: 2020-02-16T22:12:49.957, in mills: 1581891169957
Start of day: 2020-02-16T00:00:00
End of day: 2020-02-16T23:59:59.999999999
Does '2020-02-16T22:12:49.957' belong to the current day? > true
Does '2020-02-15T22:12:49.957' belong to the current day? > false
Does '2020-02-17T22:12:49.957' belong to the current day? > false
Start of week: 2020-02-10T00:00:00
End of week: 2020-02-16T23:59:59.999999999
Does '2020-02-16T22:12:49.957' belong to the current week? > true
Does '2020-02-09T22:12:49.957' belong to the current week? > false
Does '2020-02-23T22:12:49.957' belong to the current week? > false
Start of month: 2020-02-01T00:00:00
End of month: 2020-02-29T23:59:59.999999999
Does '2020-02-16T22:12:49.957' belong to the current month? > true
Does '2020-01-16T22:12:49.957' belong to the current month? > false
Does '2020-03-16T22:12:49.957' belong to the current month? > false
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough demonstration. Two suggestions: (1) Prefer `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` for a date and time that needs to represent a fixed point on the timeline. (2) Define the end of the day as the first moment of the next day *exclusive*, defining the day (and thereby the week and the month) as a *half-open* interval. It’s more correct (not excluding the last nanosecond from the day) and sometimes gives simpler code.

Answer (score 4):

I have created some methods for this:

```
public static String catchLastDayOfCurrentWeek(String pattern) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    return calendarToString(cal, pattern);
}

public static String catchLastDayOfCurrentWeek(String pattern) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1);

    return calendarToString(cal, pattern);
}

public static String catchTheFirstDayOfThemonth(Integer month, pattern padrao) {
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    return calendarToString(cal, pattern);
}

public static String catchTheLastDayOfThemonth(Integer month, String pattern) {
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), month, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    return calendarToString(cal, pattern);
}

public static String calendarToString(Calendar calendar, String pattern) {
    if (calendar == null) {
        return "";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, LocaleUtils.DEFAULT_LOCALE);
    return format.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

You can see more [here](https://github.com/albertocerqueira/java-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/java/utils/DateUtils.java).

Answer (score 3):

To get the first day of the month, simply get a `Date` and set the current day to day 1 of the month. Clear hour, minute, second and milliseconds if you need it.

```
private static Date firstDayOfMonth(Date date) {
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTime(date);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   return calendar.getTime();
}
```

First day of the week is the same thing, but using `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` instead

```
private static Date firstDayOfWeek(Date date) {
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTime(date);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
   return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Can you give any suggestions on how to extract all days of the week where the selected date is present in?

Comment: `import java.time.DayOfWeek;`  
`DayOfWeek[] daysOfWeek = DayOfWeek.values();`

Answer (score 2):

### A one-line solution using Java 8 features

In **Java**

```
LocalDateTime firstOfWeek = LocalDateTime.now().with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(); // 2020-06-08 00:00 MONDAY
LocalDateTime firstOfMonth = LocalDateTime.now().with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH , 1).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(); // 2020-06-01 00:00
// Convert to milliseconds: 
firstOfWeek.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

In **Kotlin**

```
val firstOfWeek = LocalDateTime.now().with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay() // 2020-06-08 00:00 MONDAY
val firstOfMonth = LocalDateTime.now().with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH , 1).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay() // 2020-06-01 00:00
// Convert to milliseconds: 
firstOfWeek.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

Comment: Any ideas about how to convert `LocalDateTime` to milliseconds easier?

Comment: Ah, so your idea would be to compare the millisecond values? I’d prefer to compare `Instant` objects using their `isBefore`, `isEqual` or `isAfter` method. You get an instant trivially from `Instant.ofEpochMilli(someMillisecondValue)`. And yes, the simpler way to convert a `LocalDateTime` is `firstOfWeek.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
// get today and clear time of day
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  <---- is the current hour not 0 hour
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

So the Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY returns 8, 9, 12, 15, 18 as the current running hour.
I think will be better change such line by:

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
```

this way the day always begin at 0 hour

Answer (score 1):

**Get First date of next month**:-

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String selectedDate="MM-dd-yyyy like 07-02-2018";
Date dt = df.parse(selectedDate);`enter code here`
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dt);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);

String firstDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println("firstDateof next month ==>" + firstDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert your number to a Java Calendar, e.g.:

```
 Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(myDate);
```

From there, the comparison shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
This Program will display day for, 1st and last days in a given month and year

@author Manoj Kumar Dunna
Mail Id : manojdunna@gmail.com
*/
public class DayOfWeek {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = null;
        int  year = 0, month = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter YYYY/MM: ");
        strDate = sc.next();
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        String [] date = strDate.split("/");
        year = Integer.parseInt(date[0]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(date[1]);
        cal.set(year, month-1, 1);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(cal.getTime()));
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple Solution:
package com.util.calendarutil;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CalUtil {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Date dt = null;
        try {
            dt = df.parse("23/01/2016");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dt);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        Date startDate = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        Date endDate = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("Start Date:"+startDate+"End Date:"+endDate);


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

i use this trick to get the first day of the current month
note the order is
1 for Sunday
2 for Monday
3 for Tuesday
.... and so on

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
int startDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) % 7 + 1;
System.out.println(startDay);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I don’t think you’re answering the question. Maybe a different question.

Comment: It also doesdn’t work. Running your code today, Wednesday, I got `3`, which according to you should be for Tuesday.

Answer (score -4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getMonthlyEpochList(1498867199L,12,"Monthly"));

}

public static Map<String,String> getMonthlyEpochList(Long currentEpoch, int noOfTerms, String timeMode) {
    Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    int month = 0;
    while(noOfTerms != 0) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Date monthFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Date monthLastDay = calendar.getTime();
        map.put(getMMYY(monthFirstDay.getTime()), monthFirstDay + ":" +monthLastDay);
        month--;
        noOfTerms--;
    }
    return map;     
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you are adding this as an answer?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).