# Get first day of a particular week in Joda-Time? java

Tags: java, jodatime

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), is there a way to get the date of the first day of the week(monday).

for instance i want to find out what date was this weeks monday based on todays current date 21/01/11

Cheers in advance.

edit: i also wish to find the date for the end of the week i.e sunday's date. cheers

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try [LocalDate.withDayOfWeek](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#withDayOfWeek%28int%29):

```
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
System.out.println(now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)); //prints 2011-01-17
System.out.println(now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY)); //prints 2011-01-23
```

Comment: Further tip: You can call `isBefore`/`isAfter` and `minusWeeks`/`plusWeeks` to get past/future values.

Comment: Probably will not work for countries where week starts Sundays or Saturdays

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm using Java 8 and those methods definitely do NOT exist anymore. I still can't find a solution to this problem that doesn't use Calendar.

Comment: @Zephyr Those methods are not core Java methods, but from the Joda-Time library (see question). See [this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591149/1288408) for a solution using the new Date framework from Java8.

Answer (score 27):

```
LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
LocalDate weekStart = today.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
LocalDate weekEnd = today.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue();
```

Will give you the first and last days i.e Monday and sunday

Comment: I don't think those methods exists anymore, I'm not finding them now.

Comment: @Dandre Allison please, note it is LocalDate. Methods are still there.

Comment: @sudhir Thanks, this is better answer then the accepted one. works with DateTime as well.

Comment: Perfect solution for people wondering if they should use MON or SUN to get week start, thank you!

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm using Java 8 and those methods definitely do NOT exist anymore.

Comment: @Zephyr Those are not core Java methods: they are part of the Joda-Time library. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591149/1288408) for a solution using the new Java 8 date framework. Look for `firstOfWeek`.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use [roundFloorCopy](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.Property.html#roundFloorCopy%28%29). This looks like the following:

```
LocalDate startOfWeek = new LocalDate().weekOfWeekyear().roundFloorCopy();
```

For the last day of [the standard week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) (Sunday) use [roundCeilingCopy](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.Property.html#roundCeilingCopy%28%29) and [minusDays](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays%28int%29)…

```
LocalDate lastDateOfWeek = new LocalDate().weekOfWeekyear().roundCeilingCopy().minusDays( 1 );
```

---

Also works for DateTime. And works for end of week (exclusive).

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
DateTime startOfWeek = dateTime.weekOfWeekyear().roundFloorCopy();
DateTime endOfWeek = dateTime.weekOfWeekyear().roundCeilingCopy();
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "startOfWeek " + startOfWeek );
System.out.println( "endOfWeek " + endOfWeek );
```

When run…

```
dateTime 2014-01-24T00:00:34.955-08:00
startOfWeek 2014-01-20T00:00:00.000-08:00
endOfWeek 2014-01-27T00:00:00.000-08:00
```

Comment: This code does not work for me. When I try `LocalDate startOfWeek = new LocalDate().dayOfWeek().roundFloorCopy();` or `LocalDate endOfWeek = new LocalDate().dayOfWeek().roundCeilingCopy();` I get today's date in both cases (a Thursday today). I'm using Joda-Time 2.3 and Java 8 beta 123.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for pointing me to the error. `dayOfWeek` was the wrong field. With `weekOfWeekyear` it's working as supposed to be.

Comment: Nice. That works with DateTime, even clearing the time-of-day to first moment. Is there a reason you used `LocalDate` in your code?

Comment: @BasilBourque No, this is just because the OP used 21/01/11 in his question, which is just a date without time.

Comment: Good answer. Nice approach as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [getDayOfWeek()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getDayOfWeek%28%29) method that gives you back 1 for Monday, 2 for Tue, .., 7 for Sunday in order to go back that many days and reach Monday:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

    public class JodaTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            System.out.println(date);
                    //2011-01-21T15:06:18.713Z
            System.out.println(date.minusDays(date.getDayOfWeek()-1));
                    //2011-01-17T15:06:18.713Z
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

See the section ["Querying DateTimes" of the Joda-Time user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Querying_DateTimes).

Here is the general algorithm I would follow:

1. find the day-of-week of the target date (Jan 21 2011 as you mentioned)
2. determine how many days ahead of Monday this is
3. Subtract the value of #2 from the target date using [`dateTime.minusDays(n)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusDays%28int%29)