# Getting the dates of the current week in Android

Tags: java, android, date, days

I have these 5 buttons in my program: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday, which are on my menu screen. What I want now is that when my program starts and my menu screen opens, the buttons contain the days + the dates of the day.

For example, today we're the fourth of may (happy Star Wars day!) and the buttons should be like this:

Monday 04/30
Tuesday 05/01
Wednesday 05/02
Thursday 05/03
Friday 05/04

But when I open the menu screen next monday it should be like this:
Monday 05/07
Tuesday 05/08
Wednesday 05/09
Thursday 05/10
Friday 05/11

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the java Calendar class, there is an answer here that could help you devise a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month

Comment: ok ty, I'm quite new to Java and this class Calendar will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following two threads is all you will need to get you started. And as Ian mentioned do go through the android [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) api's. Although I should mention most of the methods of Date api is deprecated. Calendar is generally preferred.

[Android Get Current Time and Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date)

[Display Current Time And Date in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-current-time-and-date-in-android-application)