# Android datepicker dialog to get days of the week

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker, android-date

I am trying to implement something similar to a timesheet so what I basically need is when I select one particular date from the datepicker dialog then I want to display a textview which contains the days of the whole week in which the selected date is present.

Below is what I have implemented to select a date from the date picket dialog.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
EditText edt1;
String  dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel1();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timesheet_form);

    edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    edt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(TimesheetForm.this, date1, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });


}
private void updateLabel1() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
    edt1.setText(sdf.format(fromCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

The above code returns the selected date from the dialog but there seems to be no method to return the days of the whole week.

Comment: will u explain more what u want to do ??

Comment: just create a method pass the date get dates of current week....[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451784/getting-the-dates-of-the-current-week-in-android)

Comment: @GauravPandey: I basically want to display all the days of the particular week where the selected date(which is acquired from datepicker dialog) is present in.

Comment: @srikanthgr: did not find it useful to extract a solution for my problem. They are more localised towards getting just one particular date from the week.

Comment: yes its just refrence u have to modify that...

Answer (score 0):

The code below is an example to get the days of the current/selected week. In my case I've set the date hardcoded to test the functionality.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Set a custom date : 2013 November 17th
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 17);

        // Date to an int variable to display
        int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

        // Display the week number
        int weekNr = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

        // Generate the String with the days of the current week
        StringBuffer weekDays = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            weekDays.append(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

            if (i < 7) {
                weekDays.append(" :: ");
            }
        }

        // Show an alert
        showAlert("Year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\nMonth : " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + 
                    "\nDay: " + date + "\n\nWeek : " + weekNr + "\n\nWeek Days : " + weekDays.toString());
```

and here the method of the alert:

```
public void showAlert(String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Date").setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
    }
```

You have to modify this a little bit, so that this fits in your code. Best practice is to create a separate method for this or add it in your updateLabel1() method and call that method from your onDateSetListener from your DatePicker.
Keep in mind that your week always starts on Sunday.

This is the result I get from this code:
[image]

Good luck,

Kr

Comment: I just tested the above but it just doesn't seem to give me the proper week. My week starts from thursday or friday. below is my code. This is how I am implementing with my datepicker

String[] items1 = edt1.getText().toString().split("/");
  
String date1=items1[0];
String month=items1[1];
String year=items1[2];
  
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(date1));
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.parseInt(month)));
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year));

//rest all is your code.