# Next week implementation in android

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar

In my sample project i have to implement next week Monday to sunday in a text view (like 6 May >> 12 My). on click of next button it must show next week start date and end date (like 13 May >> 19 May). I have implemented the intial week view with the following code

```
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
    String printDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    //gestureEvent.setText(reportDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
    String printDate2 = df2.format(c.getTime());
    gestureEvent.setText(reportDate +" >> "+reportDate2);
```

on click of next week button i have done this but it static it was just an attempt attempt 
:)

onclick will call this function goNextWeek()

```
public void goNextWeek()
{

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
        System.out.println("End Date : " + c.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
        String reportDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        gestureEvent.setText(reportDate);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dates);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        System.out.println("End Date asdfadf: " + c.getTime()); 


}
```

please tell me how to show next week start and end date?

Comment: Please post your best effort at solving the problem and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617854/get-start-and-end-of-week-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution.

```
Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
        String printDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
        String printDate2 = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());

        System.out.println(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
        gestureEvent.setText(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
```

---

**Update for implementation on button**

Write a method, which will take weekNumber as params..

```
private static String getNextWeek(int weekFromToday) {
        Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 
                mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + weekFromToday);          

        SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
        String printDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(printDate);

        //gestureEvent.setText(reportDate);
        mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
        String printDate2 = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
        return printDate + " >> " + printDate2;        
    }
```

Now declaire a static filed as

```
private static int weekNumber = -1;
```

and write below code on button click

```
weekNumber = weekNumber + 1;
gestureEvent.setText(getNextWeek(weekNumber));
```

This will work.

***Happy coding :)***

Comment: thanx :).. but can u tell me when i click again the next button i want to get the next week start and end of week like 06 May >> 12 May,13 May >> 19 May.... ?

Comment: @user2291423 see my update here.. If you have any confusion ask me

Comment: okey am using swipe and here's the implementation     if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){            
             weekNumber = weekNumber + 1;
             System.out.println("weekNumber"+weekNumber);
             gestureEvent.setText(getNextWeek(weekNumber));
            }

Comment: Check if value of weekNUmber does increments or not... Its hard to say without viewing your code.. You should make sure that value of weekNUmber must change on each call of getNextWeek()

Comment: its incrementing..i think this line mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); is making the date to start again..when comment this line an getting some output but its not correct

Comment: are u using the updated method getNextWeek()?  I don't know whats going on your side... I checked the method in loop and its working fine... and yes no need to change in method...

Comment: ok @Pankaj let me check what wrong on me anyway thanks for the help friend

Comment: Its my pleasure... we all are here for helping each other. right? :)

Comment: Hey @pankaj i have interchanged 3 and 4 th lines and its working great !!thanks buddy..and its possible to implement previous week with this code  right ? please change the code and accepting this as answer thanks buddy

Comment: Verify the update... and yes the same code will work for previous weeks but you have to pass weekNumber as negative value..

Answer (score 0):

This kind of date-time work is easier with the Joda-Time 2.3 library.

If you truly want date only without time component, modify this code to use [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class rather than [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime today = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();

// Monday
DateTime monday = today.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.MONDAY ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
if ( !(monday.isAfter( today )) ) {
    // If monday is today or earlier, move forward to future.
    monday = monday.plusWeeks( 1 );
}

// Sunday
DateTime sunday = today.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
if ( !(sunday.isAfter( today )) ) {
    // If sunday is today or earlier, move forward to future.
    sunday = sunday.plusWeeks( 1 );
}

System.out.println( "today: " + today );
System.out.println( "Monday: " + monday );
System.out.println( "Sunday: " + sunday );
```

When run…

```
today: 2013-12-08T00:00:00.000-08:00
Monday: 2013-12-09T00:00:00.000-08:00
Sunday: 2013-12-15T00:00:00.000-08:00
```