# how to show next 7 days on button click

Tags: android

I modified [this sample code](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html#comment-form) of a gridview calendar. I want to show just a single row (i.e. a week), so I added the line `if (list.size() != 7)` and it gives me the current week (seven days).

Now I want to show next week 7 days when the user click on a button. How can I do that?

Below is my code which displays current week:

```
int t;

btnnextweek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        t=7;
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});


// Current Month Days
for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
{
    Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " " + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);

    if (list.size()!=7)
    {
        if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth())
        {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
        }
        else
        {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434108/next-week-implementation-in-android/16434284#16434284