# Get a list of all the dates for the week from set date JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

Basically I am trying to create a list of all the dates for a week from a set date and store it in a `String[]` array. But I am having some trouble.

So basically, today is 09/03/2016 so in the `String[]` array I want to store:

```
09/03/2016
10/03/2016
11/03/2016
12/03/2016
13/03/2016
14/03/2016
15/03/2016
```

This is my code:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek() - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        String[] weekly = new String[7];
        Arrays.fill(weekly, "");
        int today = calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        for(int i=today; i <= today-1; i++){
            weekly[i] = Integer.toString(i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Would be great if someone could help me out

Comment: Why are trying store it in first place? Is this somehow relevant in your program? Additionally I advice using JodaTime library or in Java 8 java.time. This will let you easily put all the necessary dates in array. Simple changing it to what you want was explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20331243/4130059

Comment: Make up your mind. You say you want *"all the dates for a week from a set date"*, and your example of Wednesday March 9 to Wednesday March 16 supports that, but your code seems to try to find the first-day-of-week (Monday or Sunday). Why do that when you don't seem to want that? --- Also, your example has 8 dates listed, but your array is only 7 long. Make up your mind.

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci Further duplicates: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6617854/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10451784/642706). Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see how this `for` loop is going to work

```
for(int i=today; i <= today-1; i++){
```

If you assign the value `today` to `i` then it is going to be already greater than `today - 1`

Also you are not even using the `calendar` in your loop

How about

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    Date dt = calendar.getTime ();
    // now format it using SimpleDateFormat
    String val = df.format (dt);
    weekly[i] = val;
    calendar.add (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
}
```

Comment: The first line `Date dt = calendar.add (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1).getTime ()` does not work. You can't do `getTime()` after, was this even working for you?

Comment: Yeah, you are right it was a mistake.  `was this even working for you?` - sorry I am not going to unit test it for you.

Comment: OK, so I tried this and the first date does not start today, it starts on the `07/03/2016`

Comment: That is because in your code yo do `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek() - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))`  - WHY?

Comment: I can't remember, anyway how do I fix it?

Comment: Well `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();` will initialise it to today if that is what you want.

Comment: If you want to be a programmer you are going to have to do learn to look for information yourself e.g. javaDocs, google etc

Comment: Ok mate, don't tell me what I need to do if I wish to become a programmer - besides did I ever mention that I wanted to become a programmer? A lot of people have helped me on this forum and have been very supportive even when I have made careless mistakes and serious bugs. Not once have I been told what I needed to do if I wanted to become a programmer. I don't know what you are going to gain from that comment and unlike a lot of people I am fair. You know what, I have accepted your answer as it has helped me