# (Android) Get first day of week

Tags: android, date, calendar

How to get first day of week, when we know one of the date in the week?

I know the current month , the current year and the current date of week.
Then, are there some way to know the first day of the current week.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you searched in google..?? What you had tried.?

Answer (score 5):

hello if you need to get the first day of the current week "monday"

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  Calendar.MONDAY-calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
  Log.w(TAG, "first day of week" + calendar.getTime());
```

2 if you need the first day of the week for 20-12-2016

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2016);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.MONDAY - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    Log.w(TAG,"first day of week:"+calendar.getTime());
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

// get today and clear time of day

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

// get start of this week in milliseconds

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.println("Start of this week:       " + cal.getTime());
System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Reference :[How to get the first day of the current week and month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month)

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 2):

hello if you need to get the first day of the current week "monday"

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  Calendar.MONDAY-calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
Log.w(TAG, "first day of week" + calendar.getTime());
```

2 if you need the first day of the week for 20-12-2016

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2016);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.MONDAY - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
Log.w(TAG,"first day of week:"+calendar.getTime());
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old `Calendar` & `Date` classes.

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 23 )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
```

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate someDate = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) ;
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

To get the first day of the week, (a) decide what is the first day of the week for you, (b) use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to get the date for a specific `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
LocalDate ld = someDate.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).