# Days of the week on Android

Tags: android, calendar

I'm working on an Android app where I need to display the days of the week from the calendar. Can I do that using the calendar API ? or there is a library that can I use ?
Thanks

Comment: Display the days of the week, such as?  Getting a date and showing the day of the week?

Comment: See similar Question, [Samsung J7 returning first day of week as 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40041147/642706).

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of: [(Android) Get first day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25091904/642706)

Answer (score 0):

For date handling in Android, I recommend [310ABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), a port of the Java 8 new date APIs for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar object to get these things done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JodaTime library to display the current day of the week.

```
LocalDate newDate = new LocalDate();
int dayOfWeek = newDate.getDayOfWeek();
```

Answer (score 0):

> or there is a library that can I use ?

Yes. Use the back-port of the java.time classes. See "Android" item below.

## Using java.time

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

To get the first day of the week, (a) decide what is the first day of the week for you, (b) use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to get the date for a specific [`DayOfWeek`][6] enum object.

```
LocalDate ld = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

To get a week’s worth of dates, add a day at a time.

```
LocalDate localDate = ld ; // Initialize our looping variable.
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( 7 ) ;
for( int i = 0 , i < 7 , i ++ ) {  // Loop seven times, to cover a week.
   localDate = localDate.plusDays( i ); 
   dates.add( localDate ) ;
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).