# Samsung J7 returning first day of week as 2

Tags: android, calendar

I have written a code for custom calendar where I am using calendar object.I have used the method getFirstDayOfWeek() to retrieve first day of every month.On loading every month the method "_calendar.getTime()" returns the first date. On every device it is returning correctly.But on samsung J7 it returns starting date of week as 2 . Here is my debugger log for samsung J7

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Calcutta,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=41,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=14,DAY_OF_YEAR=288,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=46,SECOND=58,MILLISECOND=199,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

It says firstDayOfWeek = 2 , for rest of the devices it shows as 1. So any ideas for the solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution. Instead of using getFirstDayOfWeek() I passed 1 as parameter. So its working properly now.

```
 _calendar.set(year, (month - 1), 1);
```

in place of

```
_calendar.set(year, (month - 1), _calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

- You seem to conflate first-of-month with first-day-of-week.
- The `2` is a hard-coded constant representing Monday.
- Apparently your current default locale considers Monday to be the first day of the week.
- Use java.time instead.

For first day of the week:

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
```

For first day of the month:

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
         .with( ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH , 1L )
```

## Details

> getFirstDayOfWeek() to retrieve first day of every month

You seem to be confusing first of the week with first of the month.

The first of the month is always `1` of course.

The first of the week is a day-of-week such as Sunday or Monday etc. The definition of the first day of the week in the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class varies, depending on the `Locale`. For example, in much of North America, the first day is Sunday commonly. In much of Europe, the first day of the week is Monday.

If you fail to specify a `Locale`, the `Calendar` class implicitly applies the JVM’s current default locale. Apparently in your default locale the first day of the week is Monday. I deduce that because you report the number `2`. If you explore the `int` constant [`Calendar.MONDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONDAY), you find [it is indeed a primitive `int` of value `2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `Calendar` class has many poor design decisions. I consider this varying definition of day-of-week to be one of them. One of many reasons to avoid these troublesome old date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `Date`. These classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

To get the first day of the week, (a) decide what is the first day of the week for you, (b) use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to get the date for a specific [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object.

```
DayOfWeek firstDow = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;
LocalDate ld = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDow ) ) ;
```

To get a `LocalDate` for a certain day of month, call the `with` method and pass an enum object from [`ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#DAY_OF_MONTH).

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = today.with( ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH , 1L ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).