# How to get the time stamp of the first day of current week in Java?

Tags: java, calendar

What does the cal.get() method mean?

```
    public static int getTimesWeekmorning(){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONDAY), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0,0);                              
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); 
    return (int) (cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000); 
    }
```

Comment: JavaDocs for [`Calendar#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-).  If possible you should use Java 8's new Time API of Joda-Time instead.  In your case, it's just setting the current time of the `Calendar` to midnight of the current day

Comment: @MadProgrammer midnight of the current day? i need the time of the first day of the week.

Comment: Yep, that's kind of what the second `set` statement is doing.  The first `set` zeros out the time, set second changes the day of the week to `MONDAY`

Comment: @MadProgrammer how about cal.get(Calendar.MONDAY)?

Comment: What does the JavaDocs tell you?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month)