# Java : How to get Monday's date of the current week without the time and subtract it by 1 day

Tags: java

What would i like to do is get the Monday's date from the current week and subtract it by 1 day. I do not need the time with the date. I've tried below code but it gives me Sunday's date instead of Monday and also time is getting included with the date.Thanks.

```
Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -dayOfWeek);

        Date weekStart = c.getTime();
        System.out.println(weekStart);
```

Comment: Isn't Monday's Date substracted by 1 day, Sunday's Date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first day of the current week and month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month)

Comment: I'd start off by avoiding using `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`... look at the `java.time` package.

Comment: @radimpe, I'm sure your question was rhetorical, but yes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the JDK8 Date-time APIs which largely simplify these calculations.

```
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.now()
                        .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
                        .minusDays(1);
System.out.println(dt);
```

The above code gets the current date and adjust it to the current week's Monday or previous week's Monday if the current day is a Sunday. Then subtract 1 day from it, to give the Sunday's date. As LocalDate API deals with only dates, there isn't any need to take care of the time part.

Comment: Or use `DayOfWeek.SUNDAY` and lose the `minusDays`.

Comment: I recommend always passing the optional `ZoneId` object to `now` rather than implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone that can change at any moment during runtime.